# Pivot Chart - Displaying a row even when 0 results for it exist in the source data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have the following 
[pivot chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4T7i.png).

It's counting the data from the column in a different tab. The filter options for this column in are [displayed here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYLoq.png)

Sometimes this column will also contain contain cells that say "High". I want my pivot chart to always display a bar for "High", even when there are 0 results for it (like right now). How can I do this?

Comment: Does your data contain a "High" without any data in the column you are counting?

Comment: You could use a helper table maybe? The table will have two columns with 4 rows: 0, Low, Medium and High. Then you can calculate the value using `COUNTIF`, and you then only need to use this table as source for the chart instead of using a pivot table.